# Data not showing up in sharepoint list as well as in drop downs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

hi
i have a problem at my production site, client reported that he is not seeing data in lists of sharepoint, as well drop downs which have years in pages of site appear empty with one user A on machin X having with windows 7. but data and comes up and drop downs are now populated when accessed from machine Y with same user A.

i dont knw wht really the problem is. As to development site this issue is not produced,
plz help,

thnks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I gather the data does exist and the same user can see the information from one computer but not another.

A couple things spring to mind. (I am presuming usage of Internet Explorer since SharePoint 2007 has some rather weird rendering issues with other browsers. Correct me if this is an incorrect assumption.)

First, Windows 7 has later versions of IE which can refuse to send network credentials to a server it doesn't think is part of the intranet (corporate network). What makes this especially frustrating is that IE will prompt for network credentials (a result of the challenge from the website) but will not transmit those credentials. Examine the IIS logs to see if this is the case. The requests will be void of credentials using IE but will be present using Firefox (and presumably any other web browser). The fix for this is usually as simple as adding the domain into the Local Intranet zone in Internet Options.

If this is not the case, can you confirm the user is using the same credentials? Is this integrated authentication using Active Directory or forms authentication?

Are there any differences between the two computers with regards to how they reach the SharePoint site? (Such as one is VPN, the other is directly connected)? Or are they essentially equal but with different browser/OS configurations?

Are the lists standard out-of-the-box lists or have they been customized with SharePoint Designer or any other means? Are you injecting JavaScript via a Content Editor Web Part which might not be executing correctly?

It would be very helpful to know browser versions used, OS versions used, differences in connectivity to the resource from each machine, type of authentication used, and any other thing you can think to list.

I wish you luck in tracking this down!

Comment: your assumption is right for inmternet explorer. Version of OS are same i.e win 7 and both using internet explorer provided with that OS,lists are standard out of box lists, no modification is done on tht. both workstations connect to server by providing same ip addresses. users are server's local administrators, we are not allowed to add users to active directory. site is in trusted zone. i chked event veiwer and it shows some issue with network service account in dcom config and dcoumnt load balancer. fixed these errors and wating for response frm client. will let u knw soon. thnks btw :D

Comment: If this is a local network, the domain should be in the Local Intranet zone, not Trusted Sites zone. These users can see all of SharePoint but just not the list data when connecting from one particular computer but can from another? I'm trying to confirm that they aren't blocked from all of SharePoint, just some portion therein.

Comment: yeah they can see all sharepoint, but list data ain't visible to them, even site owner can not seee data frm one system, but when he logins frm other workstation data appers to him. he logins to system, clicks on list but list is empty, for other system list is not empty. wy this happens??

Comment: Given this information, it's got to be the particular workstation and not SharePoint at all. On the machine that shows the empty list, can you use a different browser to see if it sees the data? If it can, I suspect browser settings. If it can't, I suspect something wrong with the workstation. I'd check the browser version and patch level against the working machine and check to see if the same OS updates are applied.

Comment: thnks erik for ur concern to help, i guess problem is fixed, as i found some errors in event log like dcom and doc load balancer. After fixing thm prob seems to b solved, is this the possible reason for tht issues with workstation??

Comment: It might have been but I'm not sure how. Do you have more than one web front end in the farm? Ensure they all use the same machine key in the web.config - this way the sessionstate can be read and understood by them all in case a user is hitting more than one server for some reason. Sticky sessions will also help alleviate some trouble. It might just be the problem still exists on one of the front-end servers rather than the client and it's just seeing a working server now. Use a hosts file entry to test each WFE to be sure. (Using hosts file to get around load balancer and hit desired server)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 or xp has nothing to do over here probably it has to do with the browser which he is using to browse the site ask him to chk the internet explorer settings and verify that he has enabled execution of javascript and other related things